# matInput value from an array

Tags: javascript, angular, mat-input

I have an angular and angular material project where I am trying to bring a list of employees from a database and show them in a form, the form is creating the spaces correctly but the inputs are not filled with the right information, because I don't know how to link the element to the matInput.

I know that the information does arrive because as I mentioned the spaces corresponding to the number of employees are created and I can use the properties as seen in the code below.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could link the matinput with the info that arrives?

ts file and html file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { empleadoLista } from '../modelos/empleadoLista.interface';
import { RegempleService } from '../regemple.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-empleado',
  templateUrl: './empleado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empleado.component.css']
})
export class EmpleadoComponent implements OnInit {

  listaE: empleadoLista[];
  regFrom:FormGroup;

  regForm = new FormGroup({
    cdidentificacion: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    dsnombres: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    dsapellidos: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    cdtelefono: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    dsciudad: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    dsdireccion: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    cdtelefonoemergencia: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });

  constructor(private api: RegempleService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.api.getAllEmp().subscribe(data => { this.listaE = data });
    
  }


}
```

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="700px" id="registrf" *ngFor="let emp of listaE">
    <mat-grid-tile>

        <div class="example-container">
            <h2>Empleado {{emp.dsnombres}}</h2>
            <form [formGroup]="regForm">
                <div class="dosenlinea">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100 ml-2">
                        <mat-label>Identificacion</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" id="doc" formControlName="cdidentificacion" value="{{emp.cdidentificacion}}" isDisabled>

                    </mat-form-field>
                    <br>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100 ml-2">
                        <mat-label>Nombre</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" id="nombre" formControlName="dsnombres" value="{{emp.dsnombres}}">

                    </mat-form-field>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="dosenlinea">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100 ml-2">
                        <mat-label>Apellidos</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" id="apellido" formControlName="dsapellidos" value="{{emp.dsapellidos}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <br>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100 ml-2">
                        <mat-label>Telefono</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" id="tel" formControlName="cdtelefono" value="{{emp.cdtelefono}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="dosenlinea">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100 ml-2">
                        <mat-label>Ciudad</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" id="city" formControlName="dsciudad" value="{{emp.dsciudad}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <br>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100 ml-2">
                        <mat-label>Direccion</mat-label>
                        <input matInput type="text" id="dir" formControlName="dsdireccion" value="{{emp.dsdireccion}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="width-100 ml-2">
                    <mat-label>Telefono Emergencias</mat-label>
                    <input matInput type="text" id="tel_eme" formControlName="cdtelefonoemergencia" value="{{emp.cdtelefonoemergencia}}">
                </mat-form-field>
                <br>
                <div class="btsrg">
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" id="btton">
                    <span>Modificar</span>
                     </button>

                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="clear" id="btton">
                    <span>Eliminar</span>               
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: typo: `regFrom:FormGroup` - also where is `emp` coming from? Not your TS file... also try binding your values: `[value]="variable"` instead of `value="{{variable}}"`

Comment: emp comes from the ngFor is an item of the array, im gonna try the [value] to see it that could be it

Comment: you are getting list of employees. So you would need a formArray that contains formGroups. you can bind that formArray to html.

Comment: or if you need to edit only one employee info at a time. then you would need certain event so that you assign that employee info to form.